# Using NVL in where clause for a parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher, nvl

Right now I have the following query:

```
select INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_NUM, VENDOR_NUM, STATUS, GROUP_ID
from AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE 
and status in(:p_status)
and last_update_date between :p_date_from and :p_date_to
order by last_update_date, group_id
```

But this only shows if the status is either 'rejected' or 'processed'. I need it so that it also shows when the status is null. How would I include NVL to show this?

Not sure if this information is relevant but the list of values for Status has the query as

```
SELECT DISTINCT STATUS 
FROM AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE
```

Comment: NVL just takes the first non-null argument; that doesn't sound like it's what you want. What's wrong with `and (status in(:p_status)) or status is null`?

Comment: Use `and ( status in(:p_status) or :p_status IS NULL and status IS NULL ) ....`

Comment: @JoshEller thanks so much. I don't know why I thought using NVL was right for this situation.

Comment: the `where` keyword is missing..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select INVOICE_ID, 
       INVOICE_NUM, 
       VENDOR_NUM, 
       STATUS, 
       GROUP_ID
  from AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE 
 where (status in (:p_status) OR status is null)
   and last_update_date between :p_date_from and :p_date_to
 order by last_update_date, 
          group_id
```

You need close the scope of status verification to use "OR" properly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NVL is not what you need.

Try something like this:

```
select INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_NUM, VENDOR_NUM, STATUS, GROUP_ID
from AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE 
where last_update_date between :p_date_from and :p_date_to 
and (status is null or status in(:p_status))
order by last_update_date, group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `nvl` to also catch when `status = null` besides it being 'rejected' or 'processed', you can try this:

```
...
where nvl(status,'processed') in (:p_status)
  and ...
```

That way, if the `status` is `null`, the `nvl` will convert its value to 'process' and will return `true` for that condition.